# How can I get +5 to Science in Mothership Zeta?

Tags: fallout-3

I am currently just before the Spacewalk part of Mothship Zeta and about 2k short of leveling up. I have 10 intelligence and 70 Science.

I need 75 science to hack Underwood's Safe and get the MPLX novasurge.

Is there any way I can buff my science by 5 points? I'm on PS3 so I can't use the console.

Comment: PC or gaming console? If on the PC, you can use console commands to boost your stats/trigger level ups.

Comment: LMRTFY `I'm on PS3 so I can't use the console.` ;-P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick here is wait... 3 days.

After waiting for 72 hours it looks like all the aliens and robots in the Engine Room respawn. This allowed me to get the 2k experience I needed to level and put those crucial  5 points into science.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you cannot. You can however try to get one of your allies pick up the gun. I think you need to steal away their gun from their inventory. (First steal the ammo, then they will unequip their gun) Then steal the gun.

I think you then need to go into combat, and with luck, they will run to the chest open it, and pick up the gun. Somah is your best bet for this.

Looking at the wiki, going back later also isn't an option. That section of the ship is closed off after finishing the DLC.

Comment: Hmm, all the bad guys are dead so I guess I'll have to get them hostile against me. I'd better pick up all the guns on the conveyor first.

Comment: Yeah, good luck. Please report if it worked, and any other fiddely things you had to do. I'll edit them in the answer. So other have less problems.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not do this as I could not get any of my allies to follow me again.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily obtain the item by bringing one of your companions (I brought Somah) with you to the safe. once you are at the safe, simply start attacking him/her. If the gun is more powerful than the gun they are using they will pick up the pistol and attack you with it. To get it from them you can shoot it out of their hands and then put away your gun to stop the fight, try the reverse pick pocketing technique, or simply kill them. Your choice.